# Replicating Bootstrap 4 Tabs using WordPress Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, bootstrap-4, shortcode

Attempting to create Bootstrap tabs using WordPress shortcodes.

The shortcode I've build is structured in this way:

```
[tabs tabcount="3"]

   [tab title="Tab A"]
   This is Tab A content
   [/tab]

   [tab title="Tab B"]
   This is Tab B content
   [/tab]

   [tab title="Tab C"]
   This is Tab C content
   [/tab]

[/tabs]
```

User enters the number of tabs they are creating into the **tabcount** attribute and then the function should use this to output x amount of tabs and tab content areas.

```
function bootstrap_tabs_wrapper($atts, $content = null){

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'tabcount' => '',
        ), $atts
    );

    global $tabcount;
    $tabcount = $atts['tabcount'];

    $output  = '<section class="tabs" data-tabcount="'.$tabcount.'">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);
    $output .= '</section>';

    return $output;


}
add_shortcode('tabwrap', 'bootstrap_tabs_wrapper');


// actual tabs bit inside the main tab
function bootstrap_tabs_content($atts, $content = null) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'title' => '',
        ), $atts
    );


    // if currentTab is < number of tabs user has chosen in shortcode attribute
    for ($currentTab=0; $currentTab<$GLOBALS['tabcount'];$currentTab++){

        // check if first tab and add active class
        $active = '';
        if($currentTab === 0){
            echo '<nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist">';
            $active = 'active';
        }

        echo '<a class="nav-item nav-link '.$active.'" id="'.$currentTab.'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#'.$currentTab.'" role="tab" aria-controls="'.$currentTab.'" aria-selected="true">'.$atts['title'].'</a>';
    }

    echo '</nav>';


    // if currentTabContent < number of tabs user has chosen in shortcode attribute
    for ($currentTabContent=1; $currentTabContent<$GLOBALS['tabcount'];$currentTabContent++){

        // check if first tab content area and add active class
        $active = '';
        if($currentTabContent === 1){
            echo '<div class="tab-content" id="mytabContent">';
            $active = 'active';
        }

        echo '<div class="tab-pane fade show '.$active.'" id="'.$currentTabContent.'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="'.$currentTabContent.'-tab">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';

    }       
    echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('mytabs', 'bootstrap_tabs_content');
```

The issue is that the `<nav>` parts get displayed three times, rather than just three tabs displaying.

[Screenshot of Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnVRL.png)

[Screenshot of HTML layout in inspector window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cYu.png)

Comment: you have a `tabwrap` and `mytabs` shortcodes not `tabs` and `tab`

Comment: and why do you need a `tabcount`?

Comment: Apologies. The above should read as [tabwrap] and [mytabs] for the shortcode.The issue is still the same. I have used a tabcount to count and add the <a> section each time, which should display each tab in an <a> tag - the currentTab var checks against the tabcount variable. Or am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work...?

Comment: right now you are using a loop to create the tabs and the tab headers, you repeat that loop 3 times, that is why you have 3 tab headers